# Lock Pre-Filled URL Field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am new to Google Apps Scripts and do not have a coding background. I have been researching but either A) solutions I have found don't meet my needs or B) I don't understand the code. I would love some help. Here is my situation:

We have a form that we want to send out to new clients. I want their responses to be tied to their contract Id. Enter the pre-filled URL, which seems to meet my needs, however when clients are filling out the form they can edit the pre-filled information. I do not want them to be able to edit the contract ID. I have tried putting it in a section that is skipped over, but then the data doesn't save.

This ID is important because we have a additional forms that we want to send out later to collect additional information related to that contract. I want to be able to pre-fill those forms as well so that at the end of the contract, I can pull information from various forms (or sheets) into one place by referencing the contract id, which is why it is important that they not be able to edit it.

So my first need is how to lock that field. Once I get that figured out, my next task will be to figure out how to pull information from all those forms into one place . . . but one thing at a time.

Anyhelp would be appreciated . . . but it needs to be explained for a dummy. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to prefill/add an answer that can't be edited.  If the user of the Form has a Google account, you could collect the email address of the user, and link that to their account.  If that doesn't work, I think you'd need to have a custom build app that can do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to lock prefilled answers on Google Forms.

## Extended answer

The official documentation about Google Forms is on https://supports.google.com/docs. There isn't any mention about a "lock" feature for answers.

To keep your work on the G Suite platform you could use Apps Script and if you have G Suite for Business you could use App Maker.

Comment: We have G Suite for Education. So doing something like this would be possible with Apps Script? Do you have an idea of a resource to point me in the right direction. I have basic HTML experience but that is about it (and doesn't really help me here.)

Comment: @Michelle Apps Script can't modify the Google Forms respondent view built-in features but it could be used to create a web form. Regarding the right direction... What is your goal? Do you want to learn about Google Forms, about Apps Script, about creating web forms, ...?

Comment: Okay here is what I am trying to accomplish. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MZKH29x5EABvGJlYv9KpTPSr_FOiMdge?usp=sharing
I have two forms currently (but will eventually have many more forms). Each form will be sent out as part of a process. The one thing that will remain the same is the contract ID. At the beginning of a contract, the Planning for Impact form will be sent out and completed. Then the Coachable Mindset form will be sent out to the participants identified in the previous form. Eventually additional forms will be completed by others with data associated to contract.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to pull together data from all of the various forms tied to a contract and run a report (mail merge into a doc) so that all the data on a given contract can be easily viewed. From my limited capabilities and research on the internet, I can do a merge from a sheet to doc to create the report, but it only allows for pulling from one sheet. I don't really understand the script, but it accomplishes the merge portion.

Comment: This is the merge script I found and am using . . . https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RkCREWEmDLRJyffaQLtYM7NTn0d17qm9pnnDwIClPJU/edit?usp=sharing

But as I mentioned, I need all of the information from the forms on the same sheet to use it . . . and some forms will have multiple references to the same contract number. I can use a query to get data from the form response sheet to a new sheet, but don't know how to pull in the data from other sheets and have it all match up.

Comment: @MichelleHammonds It looks that you should make one or more posts. Here are some tips IMPORTRANGE Google Sheets built-in function imports data from one spreadsheet to another. If you want to use Apps Script, you could use openById or openByUrl Spreadsheet Service methods to open the spreadsheets, then you could getRange, getDataRange or copyTo methods.